# Determine student's year of study, or whether they are have graduated

Tags: excel, function, vba

I need a function that can determine whether a student is in their first, second or third year of study, or whether they are have graduated based on a) the certificate they're studying for and b) the date on which they started.

Here's my first effort - any feedback would be greatly appreciated:

[EDIT: The problem is that the function returns an error when using it in Excel]

[EDIT2: changed the m in the DateDiff section to "m" which knocked out the error - now there's just the problem that 2nd and 3rd year students are being labelled as 'Past']

```
Function YearCalc(start, course)

    'Introduce length - the course length in years
    Dim length As Integer

    'Define length corresponding to specific courses

    If course = "Msc" Then
        length = 3
    ElseIf course = "Adv Dip" Then
        length = 2
    ElseIf course = "PG Cert" Then
        length = 1
    End If

    Dim lengthm As Integer

    lengthm = (length * 12)

    'Define diff as the month difference between two dates;
    'today's date and the date the course was started.

    diff = DateDiff("m", start, Date, vbMonday)

    'Compare the date difference to the length of the course,
    'such that if the difference is larger than length of the specific course
    'the student is marked as 'Past':

    If diff >= (lengthm) Then
        YearCalc = "Past"

    'If the difference is less than the length of the course, determine which
    'year they fall into:

    Else
        If 0 <= (diff - lengthm) < 1 Then
            YearCalc = 1
        ElseIf 1 <= (diff - lengthm) < 2 Then
            YearCalc = 2
        ElseIf 2 <= (diff - lengthm) < 3 Then
            YearCalc = 3
        End If
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: So what problems are you having?

Comment: It's not returning a value, and debugging it doesn't seem to throw up anything helpful - will actually include the problem in the original post...

Comment: What error is being returned?

Comment: `DateDiff("m", start, ..` not `DateDiff(m, start, `

Comment: #VALUE! - not overly helpful.

Comment: Ah, @AlexK. - it's now returning a value - thanks. It's not returning anything higher than 1 for year of study, so now to work out the logical mistake..

Comment: `0 <= (diff - lengthm) < 1` do you mean `if (diff - lengthm) < 1`? and you seem to be comparing years when the vars hold months

Comment: I'd just noticed the latter of those two points *facepalms*

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest changing to `Select Case`, as part of the reason for only returning 1 value is the double comparison.
`0 <= AnyComparison` will always evaluate to `True`

```
Select Case course 
    Case "Msc" 
        length = 36
    Case "Adv Dip" 
        length = 24
    Case "PG Cert" 
        length = 12
End Select
```

and

```
Select Case (diff - lengthm)
    Case <0
        YearCalc = "Past"
    Case 0 to 11
        YearCalc = 1
    Case 12 to 23
        YearCalc = 2
    Case 24 to 35
        YearCalc = 3
    Case Else 
        YearCalc = "Course too long?"
End Select
```